# Remove bad local commit from Mercurial Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, mercurial

I made a wrong Merge and now would like to remove my last local commit, is there any way to do it from Eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under Undo.  As long as you haven't pushed your merge commit anywhere else you should be able to "rollback" or "strip" the merge commit.

Make sure to back up your whole repository before trying it out though.